# Python is adding values to array that I don't want it to

Tags: python, arrays, arcpy

I'm trying to take an array of field names, copy them into a new array, then add additional field names to the new array based on their similarity to the field names in the original array.
This will let me run a cursor through a table in a couple different ways... the first to get character lengths of the text to be displayed, and the second to get the text, and append the formatting information to the beginning and end of the text.

The "PointData" table has these field names 'PrimeKey', 'Label', 'Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3', 'fb_Field1', 'fp_Field1' with the formatting information held in the fb_ and fp_ fields.

```
fields = ['PrimeKey', 'Label', 'Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3']
table = "PointData"
AllFields = fields
for field in fields:
bfldnm = 'fb_' + field
pfldnm = 'fp_' + field
bfld = arcpy.ListFields(table, bfldnm)
pfld = arcpy.ListFields(table, pfldnm)
if bfld:
    AllFields.append(bfld[0].name)
bfld = []
if pfld:
    AllFields.append(pfld[0].name)
pfld = []
```

The resulting fields array ends up with the two additional field names in it ('fb_Field1' and 'fp_Field1') after running this for loop... and I can't figure out why... I ONLY want to add those two values to the AllFields array.

Comment: (`fields` and `AllFields` are actually the same, that's what `AllFields = fields` means). `AllFields = fields` -> `AllFields = fields[:]`...

Comment: wow... that simple eh?

Comment: yep. `AllFields = fields` makes both variables point to the same reference, while `AllFields = fields[:]` assigns a copy of `fields` to `AllFields`

Answer (score 2):

@njzk2 has already mentioned this, but figured I would add an answer explaining this rationale a little bit. Python does everything via [pass-by-object-reference](http://robertheaton.com/2014/02/09/pythons-pass-by-object-reference-as-explained-by-philip-k-dick/). Simply put, this means that when you do your assignment:

```
AllFields = fields
```

You aren't actually making a copy. There are a few ways to make copies in python, the simplest being via slicing hack:

```
AllFields = fields[:]
```

Others are detailed in python's [copy](https://docs.python.org/2/library/copy.html) documentation. For example:

```
import copy
AllFields = copy.copy(fields)
```

Also python traditionally uses snake case, so `AllFields` should be `all_fields`

Comment: There's also `list(fields)` as another medium-weight alternative.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks njzk2

```
   fields = ['PrimeKey', 'Label', 'Field1', 'Field2', 'Field3']
   table = "PointData"
   AllFields = fields[:]
   for field in fields:
    bfldnm = 'fb_' + field
    pfldnm = 'fp_' + field
    bfld = arcpy.ListFields(table, bfldnm)
    pfld = arcpy.ListFields(table, pfldnm)
    if bfld:
        AllFields.append(bfld[0].name)
    bfld = []
    if pfld:
        AllFields.append(pfld[0].name)
    pfld = []
```